# Как передать текущий id в модальное окно в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

пишу проект на laravel, есть таблица пользователей и напротив каждого пользователя есть кнопка, чтоб заблокировать его, при нажатии на кнопку всплывает модальное окно с формой, передаю туда текущий id пользователя в route, но он видит только первый id
сама форма:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
          Бан
        </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{$user->id}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('add_ban', $user->id)}}">
          @csrf
          <textarea name="text" id="" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="btn" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

порекомендовали сделать так :

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter{{ $user->id }}">
    Бан
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter{{ $user->id }}">
    Бан
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter{{ $user->id }}">
```

но а как передать это в route параметром так и не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что при вызове модального окна у вас уже от рендерились данные с помощью серверного языка (php в данном случае). Судя по коду, у Вас на каждом этапе цикла выводится верстка модального окна, что есть не верный подход.
А так как id один, показывается только первая в цикле. Поэтому всегда банит первого пользователя.
Окно должно быть только одно (например в футере) и в него подставляются данные в зависимости от выбранной записи.
Сразу возникает вопрос, а как быть? Данные же от рендерились и функцию `route` уже не вызвать.

Тут вам придётся подключать js без него не обойтись. На каждой итерации вывода пользователей и кнопки бан напротив каждого, добавьте ещё два `data` атрибута

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger js-btn-ban" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" 
    data-path="{{route('add_ban', $user->id)}}">
    Бан
</button>
```

Далее убираем дефолтное событие показа модального окна (data-target и data-toggle).
Модалку выносим в футер или за пределы цикла. Убираем $user->id и action у формы.
После вешаем своё событие на кнопки бана

```
const $modal = $('#exampleModalCenter');
const $titleCont = $modal.find('#exampleModalLongTitle');
const $form = $modal.find('form');

// тут ищите все кнопки (можно им какой-нибудь класс придумать уникальный, например js-btn-ban)
// далее в цикле вешаете события
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-btn-ban');
buttons.forEach(currentButton => {
    currentButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const userId = this.dataset.id;
        const path = this.dataset.path;
        $titleCont.text(userId); // выводим id пользователя
        $form.attr('action', path); // обновляем роут
        $modal.modal('show'); //показываем модалку
    });
});
```

В результате после клика на кнопку будет показываться ОДНА модалка и в ней просто будут заменяться данные

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался

Comment: @Олег пожалуйста =)